# float values in a list but ignore blanks however keep them in the list

Tags: python, list

I would like to float values in a list that include blanks.
I want to keep the blanks included in the list, therefore the code would identify the numbers and float them whilst ignoring the blanks.

I feel that my code below is missing something:

```
example  = ('','2','3','','6',' ','1','9','','4',' ')
example1 = list(example)

for i in example1:
    if i == '':
        continue
    elif i == ' ':
        continue    
    else:
        example2 = [float(i)]

example2 = [4.0]
```

my desired outcome is:

```
[blank,2,3,blank,6,blank,1,9,blank,4,blank]
```

This would show blanks in the result rather than the word 'blank'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this simple comprehension:

```
example1 = [float(x) if x.strip() else '' for x in example]
# ['', 2.0, 3.0, '', 6.0, '', 1.0, 9.0, '', 4.0, '']
```